# Different accessibility of method based on how it is declared

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

Refreshing my Javascript knowledge here so I know this is the basics of the language. In my example I can see what is happening, I just can't put into words the reason why. I've added the Chrome Console exploded object view also.

**Question:**

What is the difference between the way I have declared **MyMethod1** and **MyMethod2** in relation to accessibility in the case of

**a)** **Example.MyExample.Person** object and

**b)** for **p**, an instance of **Example.MyExample.Person**?

**Code:**

```
Example = {}
Example.MyExample = {}
Example.MyExample.Person = function(name, age, gender)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.MyMethod1 = function(){alert("My Method 1");}
};
Example.MyExample.Person.MyMethod2 = function(){alert("My Method 2");}

var p = new Example.MyExample.Person("tom", 78, "m");

p.MyMethod1(); // My Method 1
p.MyMethod2(); // p.MyMethod2 is not a function
Example.MyExample.Person.MyMethod1; // Example.MyExample.Person.MyMethod1 is not a function
Example.MyExample.Person.MyMethod2(); // My Method 2
```

**Chrome exploded object view:**

[image: Chrome Console Expanded Object View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor function return a new object each time it is called using `new`. It just help set values of properties of the new object. The new object is not equal to the constructor function:

```
new SomeClass() !== SomeClass;
```

Now, you have assigned `MyMethod2` as a property of the constructor function itself. So to access `MyMethod2` you have to use the constructor function:

```
Example.MyExample.Person.MyMethod2();
```

`MyMethod1`, however, is assigned (redifined) to each object that the call to `Person` using `new` returns. So you have to get an instance of the class to get access to `MyMethod1`. Even more:

```
var p1 = new Example.MyExample.Person();
var p2 = new Example.MyExample.Person();

p1.MyMethod1 !== p2.MyMethod1;  // because each time the constructor function get called MyMethod1 get redifined (they can be equal if they are attached to the prototype instead)
```

`MyMethod2` is what is called a **static method**.

Comment: "Now, you have assigned MyMethod2 as a property of the constructor function itself." - those were the words I was looking for to describe the clear distinction between Example.MyExample.Person, an instance of it and the way I had declared the 2 methods. Thanks.